# Best practice for login for Master-Detail App - Swift

Tags: ios

I was wondering what is the best practice to implement login screen for Master-Detail application which has SplitView Controller as a root controller. I am using the appDelegate to display the login screen if the user is not logged in. However, when I want to dismiss the loginVC the app goes into blank Detail page instead of the MasterController. Would be a modal login screen better option for Master-Detail app?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginVC") as! loginViewController
self.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
return true

let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
splitViewController.delegate = self
return true
```

And then in my loginVC:

```
@IBAction func goHome(sender: AnyObject) {
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let splitViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SplitViewControllerID") as! UISplitViewController
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
  appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = splitViewController    
    }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

By changing the code of goHome function it works for me. Below is the code:

```
@IBAction func goHome(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let splitViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SplitViewControllerID") as! UISplitViewController
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = splitViewController
    splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem
}
```